# Django Client.get() in TestCase returns TypeError from django.utils.cache

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm attempting to write a unit test for a url in my application. I used django's Client class to simulate a get() request and compare the response's status code.

Here's the test i'm running:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.shortcuts import reverse


class DashboardViewTest(TestCase):

    @patch("ordering.mixins.OrderingAppPermissionRequired.handle_not_logged_in")
    @patch("ordering.mixins.OrderingAppPermissionRequired.handle_no_profile")
    @patch("ordering.mixins.OrderingAppPermissionRequired.handle_no_id")
    def test_order_list_view(self, *mocks):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get(reverse('ordering:list'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'm facing the following error (path redacted for privacy):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[python_root]\python\python37\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1191, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "[project_root]\ordering\tests\test_dashboard.py", line 20, in test_order_list_view
    response = client.get(reverse('ordering:list'))
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 527, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 339, in get
    **extra,
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 414, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 495, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 45, in process_response
    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
  File "[virtual_env_root]\lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py", line 266, in patch_vary_headers
    vary_headers = cc_delim_re.split(response['Vary'])
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What versions of Python and Django are you running?

Comment: Python 3.7.1 and Django 2.1